# Deserialize Json Object to polymorphic C# object without typeNameHandling

Tags: c#, json, polymorphism, json.net, servicestack

My problem is I want to deserialize a json object to a C# object, but the trick is that the C# object contains List< abstract class > and this abstract class is a super class of another 10 classes.

```
public sealed class SearchAPIResult
{
    public string Status;

    public SearchAPIQuery Query;

    public SearchResults Result;

    public SearchAPIResult()
    {

    }

    public SearchAPIResult(string status)
    {
        Status = status;
    }
}
```

and `SearchAPIResult` is:

```
public sealed class SearchResults
{
    public string TextAnswer;

    public List<APIResultWidget> Items;

    public SearchResults()
    {
        Items = new List<APIResultWidget>();
    }
}
```

and here the object `APIResultWidget` is an abstract class that has about 10 classes inherit from it.

The problem is that the JSON object doesn't have something automatic (like typeNameHandling in JSON.NET) to guide the deserializer to which object of the 10 derived classes to cast to. instead the objects are marked by two fields: Type and SubType... like the following

```
{
    "Status": "OK",
    "Query": {
        "Query": "this is a query",
        "QueryLanguage": "EN"
    },
    "Result": {
        "TextAnswer": "This is your text answer",
        "Items": [{
                "Type": "list",
                "SubType": null,
                "Title": null,
                "Items": []
            }, {
                "Type": "text",
                "Content": "this is some content"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

in the previous json object, the Result list contains two objects, one:

```
{
    "Type": "list",
    "SubType": null,
    "Title": null,
    "Items": []
}
```

which maps to a class of type listWidget (which inherits from the abstract `APIResultWidget` and two:

```
{
    "Type": "text",
    "Content": "this is some content"
}
```

which maps to class `textWidget` which also inherits from the same abstract class

when I use the Json.NET way

```
SearchAPIResult converted = (SearchAPIResult)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, typeof(SearchAPIResult), new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto });
```

it throws the following exception:

> Could not create an instance of type Kngine.API.APIResultWidget. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated. Path 'Result.Items[0].Type', line 1, position 136.

I am guessing there's a custom way of pointing out that that type is defined by both the fields Type and SubType and giving the Converter that custom type annotator, is that right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deserializing polymorphic json classes without type information using json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19307752/deserializing-polymorphic-json-classes-without-type-information-using-json-net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the solution I implmented is the very basic solution, I extended the JavaScriptConverter class from System.Web.Extentions, I implemented the deseriealize method, which automatically receives each small json object in the original object as a Dictionary and I can just fill in the fields according to the object itself, it's a bit manual way, but that was the only solution that I could come up with and works, the custom class implmentation looks like this:

```
class myCustomResolver  : JavaScriptConverter

{
    public override object Deserialize(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (type == typeof(APIResultWidget))
        {
            switch ((string)dictionary["Type"])
            {
                case "weather":
                    {
                        WeatherWidget x = new WeatherWidget();
                        x.Location = (string)dictionary["Location"];
                        x.Current = (CurrentWeather)dictionary["Current"];
                        //x.Forcast = (List<WeatherForcastItem>)dictionary["Forcast"];

                        System.Collections.ArrayList itemss = ((System.Collections.ArrayList)dictionary["Forcast"]);
                        foreach (var item in itemss)
                        {
                            x.Forcast.Add(serializer.ConvertToType<WeatherForcastItem>(item));
                        }

                        return x;
                    };
                case "text":
                    {
                        TextWidget x = new TextWidget();
                        x.Content = (string)dictionary["Content"];
                        return x;
                    }; 
                case "keyValueText":
                    {
                        KeyValueTextWidget x = new KeyValueTextWidget();
                        x.Key = (string)dictionary["Key"];
                        x.Key = (string)dictionary["Value"];
                        x.Key = (string)dictionary["ValueURL"];
                        return x;
                    };
                case "keyValuesText":
                    {
                        KeyValuesTextWidget x = new KeyValuesTextWidget();
                        x.Key = (string)dictionary["Key"];
                        //x.Values = (List<ValueItem>)dictionary["ValueItem"];

                        System.Collections.ArrayList itemss = ((System.Collections.ArrayList)dictionary["ValueItem"]);
                        foreach (var item in itemss)
                        {
                            x.Values.Add(serializer.ConvertToType<ValueItem>(item));
                        }


                        return x;


                    }; 
                case "url":
                    {
                        URLWidget x = new URLWidget();
                        x.ThumbnailImageURL = (string)dictionary["ThumbnailImageURL"];
                        x.Title = (string)dictionary["Title"];
                        x.URL = (string)dictionary["URL"];
                        x.HTMLContent = (string)dictionary["HTMLContent"];
                        return x;

                    }; 
                case "map":
                    {
                        MapWidget x = new MapWidget();
                        System.Collections.ArrayList itemss = ((System.Collections.ArrayList)dictionary["Pins"]);
                        foreach (var item in itemss)
                        {
                            x.Pins.Add(serializer.ConvertToType<MapPoint>(item));
                        }

                        //x.Pins = (List<MapPoint>)dictionary["Pins"];
                        return x;

                    }; 
                case "image":
                    {
                        ImageWidget x = new ImageWidget();
                        x.Title = (string)dictionary["Title"];
                        x.ImageURL = (string)dictionary["ImageURL"];
                        x.ThumbnailURL = (string)dictionary["ThumbnailURL"];
                        x.PageURL = (string)dictionary["PageURL"];
                        return x;
                    }; 
                case "html":
                    {
                        HTMLWidget x = new HTMLWidget();
                        x.Title = (string)dictionary["Title"];
                        x.HTML = (string)dictionary["HTML"];
                        return x;


                    }; 
                case "entity":
                    {
                        EntityWidget x = new EntityWidget();
                        x.SubType = (string)dictionary["SubType"];
                        x.Title = (string)dictionary["Title"];
                        x.Abstract = (string)dictionary["Abstract"];
                        x.ImageURL = (string)dictionary["ImageURL"];
                        x.Url = (string)dictionary["Url"];
                        return x;

                    }; 
                case "chart":
                    {
                        ChartWidget x = new ChartWidget();
                        x.Title = (string)dictionary["Title"];
                        //x.Categories = (List<string>)dictionary["Categories"];
                        System.Collections.ArrayList itemss = ((System.Collections.ArrayList)dictionary["Categories"]);
                        foreach (var item in itemss)
                        {
                            x.Categories.Add(serializer.ConvertToType<string>(item));
                        }



                        System.Collections.ArrayList itemss2 = ((System.Collections.ArrayList)dictionary["Data"]);
                        foreach (var item in itemss2)
                        {
                            x.Data.Add(serializer.ConvertToType<ChartsData>(item));
                        }

                        //x.Data = (List<ChartsData>)dictionary["Data"];
                        return x;
                    }; 
                case "businessEntity":
                    {
                        BusinessEntityWidget x = new BusinessEntityWidget();
                        x.SubType = (string)dictionary["SubType"];
                        x.Title = (string)dictionary["Title"];
                        x.Abstract = (string)dictionary["Abstract"];
                        x.ImageURL = (string)dictionary["ImageURL"];
                        x.URL = (string)dictionary["URL"];
                        //x.Attributes = (List<KeyValueTextWidget>)dictionary["Attributes"];
                        System.Collections.ArrayList itemss = ((System.Collections.ArrayList)dictionary["Attributes"]);
                        foreach (var item in itemss)
                        {
                            x.Attributes.Add(serializer.ConvertToType<KeyValueTextWidget>(item));
                        }

                        x.Address = (string)dictionary["Address"];
                        x.Phone = (string)dictionary["Phone"];
                        x.Lat = (double)dictionary["Lat"];
                        x.Lng = (double)dictionary["Lng"];


                        System.Collections.ArrayList itemss2 = ((System.Collections.ArrayList)dictionary["OtherURLs"]);
                        foreach (var item in itemss2)
                        {
                            x.OtherURLs.Add(serializer.ConvertToType<URLWidget>(item));
                        }
                        //x.OtherURLs = (List<URLWidget>)dictionary["OtherURLs"];

                        return x;



                    }; 

                case "list":
                    {
                        switch ((string)dictionary["SubType"])
                        {
                            case null:
                                {
                                    ListWidget x = new ListWidget();
                                    x.Title = (string)dictionary["Title"];
                                    System.Collections.ArrayList itemss = ((System.Collections.ArrayList)dictionary["Items"]);
                                    foreach (var item in itemss)
                                    {
                                        x.Items.Add(serializer.ConvertToType<APIResultWidget>(item));
                                    }
                                    return x;

                                }; 
                            case "videos":
                                {
                                    ListOfVideosWidget x = new ListOfVideosWidget();

                                    System.Collections.ArrayList itemss = ((System.Collections.ArrayList)dictionary["Items"]);
                                    foreach (var item in itemss)
                                    {
                                        x.Items.Add(serializer.ConvertToType<URLWidget>(item));
                                    }
                                    return x;
                                }; 
                            case "images":
                                {
                                    ListOfImagesWidget x = new ListOfImagesWidget();


                                    System.Collections.ArrayList itemss = ((System.Collections.ArrayList)dictionary["Items"]);
                                    foreach (var item in itemss)
                                    {
                                        x.Items.Add(serializer.ConvertToType<ImageWidget>(item));
                                    }
                                    return x;
                                }; 
                            case "webResults":
                                {

                                    ListOfWebsitesWidget x = new ListOfWebsitesWidget();

                                    System.Collections.ArrayList itemss = ((System.Collections.ArrayList)dictionary["Items"]);
                                    foreach (var item in itemss)
                                    {
                                        x.Items.Add(serializer.ConvertToType<URLWidget>(item));
                                    }
                                    return x;
                                }; 
                            case "businesses":
                                {
                                    ListOfBusinessesWidget x = new ListOfBusinessesWidget();
                                    x.Title = (string)dictionary["Title"];
                                    System.Collections.ArrayList itemss = ((System.Collections.ArrayList)dictionary["Items"]);
                                    foreach (var item in itemss)
                                    {
                                        x.Items.Add(serializer.ConvertToType<BusinessEntityWidget>(item));
                                    }
                                    return x;
                                }; 



                        }
                    }; break;


            }
        }

        else //in case of objects not inheriting from the abstract class, in this case we identify each one by something else, not "type"
        {
            if (dictionary.ContainsKey("Day")) //WeatherForcastItem
            {
                WeatherForcastItem x = new WeatherForcastItem();
                x.Day = (string)dictionary["Day"];
                x.Hi = (string)dictionary["Hi"];
                x.Lo = (string)dictionary["Lo"];
                x.Status = (string)dictionary["Status"];
                x.IconURL = (string)dictionary["IconURL"];
                return x;

            }
            else if (dictionary.ContainsKey("Temprature")) // CurrentWeather
            {
                CurrentWeather x = new CurrentWeather();
                x.Temprature = (string)dictionary["Temprature"];
                x.Status = (string)dictionary["Status"];
                x.WindSpeed = (string)dictionary["WindSpeed"];
                x.WindDirection = (string)dictionary["WindDirection"];
                x.Humidity = (string)dictionary["Humidity"];
                x.IconURL = (string)dictionary["IconURL"];
                x.IsNight = (string)dictionary["IsNight"];
                return x;

            }
            else if (dictionary.ContainsKey("Lat")) //MapPoint
            {
                MapPoint x = new MapPoint();
                x.Title = (string)dictionary["Title"];
                x.Lat = (double)dictionary["Lat"];
                x.Lng = (double)dictionary["Lng"];
                return x;
            }
            else if (dictionary.ContainsKey("Value")) //ValueItem
            {
                ValueItem x = new ValueItem();
                x.Value = (string)dictionary["Value"];
                x.ValueURL = (string)dictionary["ValueURL"];
                return x;
            }
            else if (dictionary.ContainsKey("name")) //ChartsData
            {
                ChartsData x = new ChartsData();
                x.name = (string)dictionary["name"];
                System.Collections.ArrayList itemss = ((System.Collections.ArrayList)dictionary["name"]);
                foreach (var item in itemss)
                {
                    x.values.Add(serializer.ConvertToType<string>(item));
                }
                return x;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public override IDictionary<string, object> Serialize(
 object obj,
 JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
    { return null; }

    private static readonly Type[] _supportedTypes = new[]
{
    typeof( APIResultWidget )
};

    public override IEnumerable<Type> SupportedTypes
    {
        get { return _supportedTypes; }
    }

}
```

that should map each json object to it's right class, the usage of the deseriealizer is fairly easy then:

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
serializer.RegisterConverters(new[] { new myCustomResolver() });
var dataObj = serializer.Deserialize<SearchAPIResult>(response);
```

this solved the deserialization issue I was having with the abstract classes, because it totally worked around how the classes are related to each other in the first place. I don't know if this is the most right solution or not, but at least it solved my porblem

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is a better way to deserialize objects:

```
var converted = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SearchAPIResult>(json);
```

Anyway, I think your problem is that you are trying to instruct the serializer to deserialize the Item property with only a List of APIResultWidget. Can you update your post with that class? It could be easier to us to help you.

Comment: APIResultWidget is just an abstract class that's actually empty

Answer (score 0):

By default ServiceStack only serializes **public properties**. To get it to serialize public fields as well you need to configure it with:

```
JsConfig.IncludePublicFields = true;
```

Comment: it's not a serialization issue, it's a deserialization issue, I cannot manipulate the serialization process.